# Ubuntu 18 appearance and style changed drastically on Jetson

Tags: 18.04, arm

I installed a few generic programs on my Jetson to run a few projects, and after rebooting, the entire appearance of the OS has seemed to change.  Previously it was an "Ubuntu-style" desktop and settings, but now it is more Windows-like.

Everything I’ve installed is the same that I’ve done on other Jetson machines, so I am not sure what might have caused this, and I don’t know how to revert it.

Specifically, since the last time I rebooted, I’ve installed Boost, asio, nlohmann json, cpp socketio. None of these should change the entire look-and-feel. I would appreciate any insight on how to revert it.

In addition to the packages I've listed above, I probably also added a few packages on which they are dependent, so it's possible they could have perhaps caused this.  But again, I've done the same thing on other Jetson machines without this issue.

Desktop:

[image: Screenshot 1]

File manager:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: You mention 18 in the title (closest Ubuntu product being Ubuntu Core 18), but have tagged a different 18.04 release?  Please be precise with details; Ubuntu Core 18 (a *year* format product) are different to those using the *year.month* format.  What OS & release details are you using?  What kernel please also, ie. are you using a Ubuntu product?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the "start menu" icon is from LXDE Desktop. Also found: `Note: Jetson Nano 2GB Developer Kit uses the memory-efficient LXDE desktop environment with Openbox window manager. Check out some basic Openbox info and tips if you are more accustomed to other Linux desktops (or are new to Linux entirely).` in Nvidia's documentation